# Is using spyOn() without a method possible?

Tags: jasmine, spyon

I'm new to jasmine and spies thing, hope you could point to the right direction.

I have an event listener that i want to cover with unit test:

```
    var nextTurn = function() {
    continueButton.addEventListener("click", displayComputerSelection)
};

nextTurn();
```

The general idea is to spy the 'displayComputerSelection' function .

`it ("should call fn displayComputerSelection on continueButton click", function(){
        spyOn(displayComputerSelection);
        continueButton.click();
        expect(displayComputerSelection).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Since the basic structure of spies is `spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)` i get a response `No method name supplied` . 
I've tried experimenting with jasmine.createSpy but couldn't make it work.
How would i substitute for the method that is expected?

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem**

In your scenario, the whole question is how or where is `displayComputerSelection` defined, because this func is what you want to replace with your spy.

**jasmine.createSpy()**

It is `jasmine.createSpy()` that you want. For instance, the following is an example for how you can use it - totally untested - no pun intended.

```
var objectToTest = {
  handler: function(func) {
    func();
  }
};

describe('.handler()', function() {
  it('should call the passed in function', function() {
    var func = jasmine.createSpy('someName');

    objectToTest.handler(func);

    expect(func.calls.count()).toBe(1);
    expect(func).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
  });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks !
`displayComputerSelection` is a global variable, so i found out i simply needed to use `window`as an object.

So it worked this way:

`spyOn(window, "displayComputerSelection");`

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my specific case was:

```
it ("should call displayComputerSelection on continueButton click", function(){
    spyOn(window, "displayComputerSelection");
    start(); //first create spies, and only then "load" event listeners
    continueButton.click();
    expect(window.displayComputerSelection).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Browser seems to hook up global var/functions to the 'window' object, thus it is to be spied upon.